# Download content of app at download of application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My problem is that my application size is very high.
so i want that user download application and when required content then content is downloaded in user iphone memory.
and if one time downloaded content then user never required to download content again and again.

is it possible?

please tell me if any reference.

Thanks,

Arun

Answer (score 3):

You can download any needed medias in your app document folder.

You can get it's URL that way :

```
  [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]
```

or

```
NSString *homeDir = NSHomeDirectory();
NSArray *arrayPaths = 
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSDocumentDirectory,
        NSUserDomainMask,
        YES);

NSString *docDir = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i m implementing in my project
.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084557/xcode-slow-to-install-on-simulator-and-device/3085098#3085098)  Basically, you store all your content in a directory.  If the directory exists, do nothing.  Else, download a zip file and unzip the contents into the directory.  It's all detailed in the link above.